# pgfplots - How can the axis labels be positioned at the arrow head with `axis lines=left`?

Tags: pgfplots, positioning

In `pgfplots`, I am creating a plot of a function that is only in the first quadrant of the Cartesian coordinate system.
I am using the `axis lines=left` option.
My problem is that I would like to display the axis labels, "x" and "y", at the end of the axis lines, i.e. centered at the arrow tip, as shown in the picture below.

[image: photo]

Minimum working code to produce the image above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            x=1cm,
            y=1cm,
            xmin=0, xmax=5,
            ymin=0, ymax=5,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ticks=none,
            axis lines=left
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I do not want ticks on the plot, so `ticks=none`. 
I also tried using `axis lines=center`, and that put the labels near the arrow tips, but did not center them above/next to the arrow tips and also cut off part of the arrow tips.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! You can change the position with e.g.

```
xlabel style = {at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=north east},
ylabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0,1)},anchor=south east},
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel style = {at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=north east},
            ylabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0,1)},anchor=south east},
            x=1cm,
            y=1cm,
            xmin=0, xmax=5,
            ymin=0, ymax=5,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            ticks=none,
            axis lines=left
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I rotate the y-label 90° to the right and display it centered above the arrow tip?

Comment: @Georg `ylabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0,1)},anchor=south,rotate=-90},` and you're welcome!